# two inner join in one sql statement

Tags: mysql

What's wrong here ? i just want to display all the item in *item_tb* with 2 different group , vicma and branch but it returns nothing. It only works in one inner join but when i join the other one it display nothing.

```
 |-------------|-------------------------|---------------|
 |item_tb      | vicma_tb                | branch_tb     |
 |             |  vID - PK               |   id-PK       |
 |branchID-FK  |                         |               |
 |vicma - FK   |                         |               |
 |-------------|-------------------------|---------------|


$sql = "
SELECT item_tb.*
     , branch_tb.* 
     , vicma_tb.* 
  from item_tb 
  JOIN branch_tb 
    on item_tb.branchID = branch_tb.id 
  JOIN vicma_tb  
    on item_tb.vicma = vicma_tb.vID ";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need to do a LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN. LEFT JOIN will return all values from your original table and NULL if there is no match. Try:

```
SELECT  item_tb.*, branch_tb.* , vicma_tb.* from item_tb 
LEFT JOIN  branch_tb on item_tb.branchID = branch_tb.id 
LEFT JOIN vicma_tb on item_tb.vicma = vicma_tb.vID
```

Comment: Thanks . Got it :)